# Automate connection to SFTP server (FileZilla)

Tags: batch-file, automation, sftp

I would like to automate the connection to an SFTP server (FileZilla) in order to create a batch file to automate some reporting processes.

What I used until now is the following script:

```
sftp alessandro:arica.123@85.148.385.22
```

Theoretically, I am passing in the script above the username (alessandro), the password (arica) and the hostname. The problem is that the password is not passed as a parameter, therefore in order to connect, I am asked to enter the password in the terminal.

Can you explain me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: FileZilla is not SFTP server. What makes your question bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you explain me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

The manual page for `sftp` explain synopsis of `sftp` command this way (abbreviated):

```
 sftp [...] [user@]host
```

As you can see, there is no `:password` so both of `username:password` are passed as a username to the server. `sftp` command does NOT accept passwords on command-line, because it is very bad security practice to store the passwords in plain text in scripts.

You should configure your server to accept public key authentication (it is not so hard and very useful for automation!):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ssh-copy-id alessandro@85.148.385.22    # write password once
ssh alessandro@85.148.385.22            # will not ask for password again
```